# Getting Invalid cursor state(SQL exception)

Tags: java, sql, sqlexception, insert-update

I have this Code Where i am inserting some values in database. I am getting an Invalid Cursor State Exception. What may be the reason ... I am first selecting some values from a table(Select statement) which i need to insert into another table. I am doing 2 insert operations over here..

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.*"%>
<%@page import="java.util.*"%>
<%@page import="models.app.*"%>
<%-- <%@page import="MyPackage.*;"%> --%>

<%
String id = request.getParameter("employeeidname");
int offshore = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("offshorename"));
String email = request.getParameter("emailidname");
String profile = request.getParameter("profilename");
String empname = request.getParameter("employeenamename");
String projectname = request.getParameter("projectname");


/* HandleConnections con = new HandleConnections(); */
Connection con=null;
try{
    String driver = "sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver";
Class.forName(driver);

String db = "jdbc:odbc:Practice_Database";
con = DriverManager.getConnection(db,"","");
ResultSet rs=null;
Statement st2 =con.createStatement();
Statement st3 =con.createStatement();
Statement st = con.createStatement();
String sql1="SELECT Project_ID FROM Project_Table WHERE Project_Name = '"+projectname+"'";
rs= st2.executeQuery(sql1);
String sql ="INSERT into Emp_Product_Project_Mapping(Emp_IDFK, Project_IDFK) values('"+id+"',"+rs.getInt("Project_ID")+")";
int j = st3.executeUpdate(sql);
/* conn = con.getConnection(); */

SendMail send = new SendMail();
Generator gen1 = new Generator();
String temp = gen1.gen(8);
send.sendmail("shantanu.tomar@gmail.com", email, temp);

String sql2= "INSERT into Employee_Table(Emp_ID,F_Name,Profile,Offshore,Email,Password) values('"+id+"','"+empname+"','"+profile+"',"+offshore+",'"+email+"','"+temp+"')";
int i = st.executeUpdate(sql2);
if(i==1)
out.println("Values inserted successfully");
}
catch(Exception e){
    System.out.print(e);
    e.printStackTrace();
    }


%>
```

The URL from where i am getting the values is ::

```
http://localhost:8080/2_8_2012/jsp/Addemployeedatabase.jsp?employeeidname=A12&offshorename=2&emailidname=Mayur.Sharma@gmail.com&profilename=GL&employeenamename=Mayur&projectname=INFRASTRUCTURE
```

Exception ::

```
[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Invalid cursor statejava.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Invalid cursor state
```

Solved By using ::

```
while(rs.next) to retrieve values from result set...
```

Comment: Which statement gives the error? Have you tried running each statement with the others commented out? What database are you connecting to?

Comment: My final insert Statement i.e Insert into Employee_Table.. is working fine... When i comment everything else. I think there's a prob with st2 and st3 statements ...

Comment: Do i need to have separate connection variables for each statement... ??

Comment: Could the problem be that your DB doesn't allow an active cursor when making additional statements? I.e. Do you need to close the result set (rs) before making the insert statement (Or read the entire data into memory, construct statements, close the result set, and then execute the following statements)?

Comment: No, you don't need separate connection variables, I think you might just need to "complete" each statement. If the result set is opening a cursor to the DB, then you can't run any other statements while its still open. Perhaps.

Comment: so u saying that first i save the value of rs.getint in some var xyz and then use it in insert query .. ??

Comment: Before you call st3.executeUpdate(sql);, try a rs.Close(); (and maybe st2.Close() if it has a Close method).

Comment: String sql1= "SELECT Project_ID FROM Project_Table WHERE Project_Name = '"+projectname+"'";
rs= st2.executeQuery(sql1);
int var = rs.getInt("Project_ID");
rs.close();
st2.close();
String sql = "INSERT into Emp_Product_Project_Mapping(Emp_IDFK, Project_IDFK) values('"+id+"',"+var+")";
int j = st3.executeUpdate(sql);

Comment: have tried the above.. But still gives me the same error..

Comment: I gt that .. while(rs.next()) statement was missing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you literally want simultaneous independent statement execution then you want multiple connection objects, typically managed via a connection pool.

Beware though that not all drivers support multiple Statements per Connection, most notably the JDBC-ODBC bridge

Comment: I gt that ... While(rs.next()) statement was missing... Thanks for your ans though.. Gt the point what u trying to say .. :)

Comment: @user1230183: if this answer helped you, them mark it as correct (i.e tick mark it from left side of the answer)